# How to get datetime as output using shell script linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to return datetime as just numbers without any special characters
ex:20210621162050

the shell script i have is

```
input_file="/./../$1/securityVA"
inputfile_date=`date "+%Y%M%d%h%s"`
echo $inputfile_date
```

i want to something like date and 6 digits only such as 162050 but i get 2021june2111639292383

Comment: Q: How to get datetime as output?  A: Read the documentation: [man date](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html).  It *looks* like you're trying to do that... but it's unclear from your description exactly what you want.  SUGGESTION: Experiment with different format values until you get it right.

Comment: Maybe you want the digits like HHMMSS, such as `date '+%H%M%S'` in bash, as paulsm4 mention, you should get the usage of `date` by `man date`, the section `FORMAT controls the output` in `man date`'s DESCRIPTION will show what you want.